# Listview dynamic listing: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using listview to place items dynamically in the asp:imagebutton(from database). Now i want to fetch the changing imagebutton id to display dynamic items in listview2. here is my code: 
**.cs page**
     protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        ListViewItem item = ListView1.Items[ListView1.SelectedIndex];

        ImageButton c = (ImageButton)item.FindControl("imgButton");
        var result = c.AccessKey;
        if (result == "3")
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da2.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Forms where Module_ID=3 ", conn);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            da2.Fill(dt2);
            ListView2.DataSource = dt2;
            ListView2.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

**aspx. page**

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href='<%# Eval("Module_Redirect") %>'>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton" AccessKey='<%# Eval("Module_ID") %>' AlternateText="Image Here" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Module_img") %>' OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" runat="server" />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

the code is showing error as above. help me to remove this please...

Comment: You probably have a startup issue.  That code is being run before the Initialize() method is run.  The ListViewItem count is set to -1 before data is added to listview.  So checking for item count > 0 needs to be added to code.

Comment: adding the check for item count didn't solve the problem yet. this line is again highlighted with the same error @jdweng

Comment: help me to solve the issue please.

Comment: Either the ListView is null, count is less than zero, or count is greater than number of rows.  Is this the 1st time ListView is being filled?  The count of rows may be different in aspx than c#.  What sometimes works is : ListView2.DataSource = null; ListView2.DataSource = dt2;  Setting to null forces the form to update.  You may be missing a Update() Event in the aspx code.

Comment: listview2 is also filled in the pageload() of this page. but i want it to be updated as i click on the item of listview1. listview1's selectedindex is creating issue

Comment: Then don't you need to check for both ListView1 and ListView2 both being > 0?